# how to translate matlab function max(y(x>3)>2) to numpy in single line

Tags: python, matlab, numpy

i want to convert matlab functions like all, any, max min to numpy.

since these functions takes compound expressions as inputs, wanted to know how to achive the same in numpy.

for ex. max(y(x>3)>2)

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
y = [2,4,6,8,9,2]
```

in matlab i would have got the answer as 9

how can i write the above max function in numpy so that it accepts the diffrent expressions.

like

```
max(x>3) - ans 6
max((x>3)>5) - ans 6
max((x>3) & (x<6)) - ans 5
```

thanks a lot for your inputs in advance.

Comment: you don't use `y` in any of your examples.

Comment: Your examples are wrong. In Matlab `max(x>3)` will return `1` or `true`. The same for all your examples...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not so short, but one-liner:

```
max([y[i] for i in range(len(y)) if x[i] > 3 and y[i]>2])
```

Answer (score 6):

In general ([http://wiki.scipy.org/NumPy_for_Matlab_Users](https://web.archive.org/web/20150818181140/http://wiki.scipy.org/NumPy_for_Matlab_Users)) is a very good guide for making the conversion from MATLAB -> numpy

```
x = np.array(x)
np.max(x[x>3])
np.max(x[(x>3)*(x>5)])
np.max(x[(x>3)*(x<6)])
```

Comment: This is the better answer: it uses numpy, as was requested, and is about 50 times faster.  btw, the original formula would be `y[(x>3)&(y>2)].max()` or `np.max(y[(x>3)&(y>2)])`.